# How to fully reproduce dev environment with ddev?

Tags: 7

I'm `git clone`ing a project that is run with `ddev`. After doing

- `git clone`
- `ddev config`
- `ddev start`

and opening the hosted site, I get various errors, for instance:

```
    Warning: include_once(/var/www/html/includes/file.phar.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in include_once() (line 716 of /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
    Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/includes/file.phar.inc' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in include_once() (line 716 of /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
    Error: Call to undefined function file_register_phar_wrapper() in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 717 of /var/www/html/includes/bootstrap.inc).
    Notice: Undefined index: base_url in file_create_url() (line 395 of /var/www/html/includes/file.inc).
    Notice: Undefined index: base_url in file_create_url() (line 395 of /var/www/html/includes/file.inc).
    Notice: Undefined index: base_path in base_path() (line 2930 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).
    Notice: Undefined index: base_path in base_path() (line 2930 of /var/www/html/includes/common.inc).
```

My colleagues don't get this of course. And the file `file.phar.inc` is indeed not present in the entire repo. This shows that this isn't a small bug in the Drupal code but rather something is different about our environments. How can I get a reproducible build running on my machine? Should I copy the entire `.ddev` folder from a working installation to my machine and rerun `ddev`?

ps. I did try copying down `file.phar.inc` file from the Drupal source and this got rid of the include error, but generated many more other ones. I could go down the rabbit hole of fixing all of them but it works on other devs' machines, so I think it's an environment issue.

Comment: It suggests that not all of Drupal is present on whichever commit your working copy is on. Can you form this into a question that we could answer? It’s sort of unanswerable as it is.

Comment: I think the question is clear. Other devs pull down the site as-is, run ddev, and it works. On my machine it gives the above errors. This leads me to assume I'm misusing ddev. My question is: What am I doing incorrectly? How can I reproduce a Drupal site on my local machine using ddev?

Comment: Alright, what does `git status` say? Is your working copy checked out on the same branch as that of your teammates’?  Like I said you are missing files from Drupal.

Answer (score -1):

Did you run `ddev composer install` from the project root?

Newer versions of Drupal use composer to manage dependencies. Generally, composer projects don't commit these files so you need to "install" them after cloning: `composer install`

Because your project is using ddev, you need to run `ddev composer install` (which runs the command inside the web container) to make sure composer uses your site's PHP version.

Comment: The question was tagged with the `7` tag, meaning its for Drupal 7 and not 8+.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new-ish to the platform and was unaware of this convention.